# Iterate over pandas dataframe in jinja2

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2

I have this dataframe:

```
        id       text
 0      12       boats
 1      14       bicycle
 2      15       car
```

Now I want to make a select dropdown in jinja2. But I cannot find a way to loop over the dataframe in jinja2.

I tried using to_dict(). But with

```
{% for key,value in x.items() %}
```

it loops over id and text instead of the rows. How can I change this so I can do something like this in the template?

```
{% for key,value in x.items() %}
    <option value="{{ id }}">{{ text }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [`df.iterrows()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) is used to Iterate over DataFrame rows as (index, Series) pairs. In place of `x.items()`.

Comment: Thanks this worked

Comment: Please copy your solution into an answer and then you can accept it yourself.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As John Galt suggested this works:

```
{% for key,value in x.iterrows() %}
      <option value="{{ value['id'] }}">{{ value['text'] }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think it would be clearer to use `for index, row` instead of the generic `for key, value`.