# Pandas Dataframe in Flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I have a pandas dataframe by using this code:

```
frame['count'] = 1
frame['age_group'] = pd.cut(frame.age, [0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100])

age_grp = frame.pivot_table('count', index='age_group', columns='gender', aggfunc='sum').fillna(0).
```

and the dataframe looks like this

```
     gender       F      M
    age_group       
    (0, 10]     0.0     0.0
    (10, 20]    0.0     0.0
    (20, 30]    2.0     0.0
    (30, 40]    6.0     5.0
    (40, 50]    15.0    4.0
    (50, 60]    35.0    24.0
    (60, 70]    47.0    30.0
    (70, 80]    24.0    6.0
    (80, 90]    1.0     2.0
    (90, 100]   0.0     0.0
```

How can I loop this dataframe properly? im planning to use a double bar chart using chartjs with this data.

*attempting to try this 
[iterate over pandas dataframe in jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40830975/iterate-over-pandas-dataframe-in-jinja2)

```
{% for key,value in x.iterrows() %}
      <option value="{{ value['id'] }}">{{ value['text'] }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

trying to print the boundaries.

Comment: what do you mean "loop this dataframe properly"?

Comment: I loop a pandas series using  {% for i,value in cases_gender.iteritems() %}

         *insert codes*
     {% endfor %}

Comment: @thesilkworm when I use to json I cannot view anymore the boundaries of the data?

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do - will remove the to_json comment as I don't think it is what you were looking for.

Comment: well I can still the data, I think I can do something around it but I dont see the boundaries anymore in the json format

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for.

```
 {% for key,value in dm_cases_age_grp.iterrows() %}
                                console.log('{{ value['F'] }}')
                                console.log('{{ value['M'] }}')
                                    console.log('{{ key }}')
                            {% endfor %}
```